# LG G4 H815 no sim signal

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 5.0-lollipop, device-firmware, lg-g4, baseband

I have just flashed a Europe firmware meant for H815 to H815T. In doing so I have upgraded from lollipop to marshmallow. The firmware is so smooth and fast except that there is a big problem. NO SIM signal. I know that this is because of some base band problem. Can you guys please guide me on what to do?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

All the firmware are not Fully Stable. May be the firmware you installed doesn't have a sim support. You can simply change your custom firmware or get back your original firmware. You can have a stable `Rom` from `Cyanogenmod`. It really provides stable `Rom's` and mostly stable one's.

Comment: I doubt that it was not stable cause that's the official one. Added to this is the fact that I had tried two of them. Can you please tell me the steps to rectify this issue, as by flashing modem.bin etc?

Comment: Going in the way of flashing modem.bin is too long. You can simply flash any version of cyanogenmod. It is best custom rom provider with least bugs and have a sim support. As if you are wondering about your current rom stability, if it was a stable one then your phone should be able to get network

Comment: Oh I see. By the way can you please verify that if I will flash CWM then I am starting from scratch, i.e. all the issues (if any) will get fixed, even if I had flashed something rom previously, right?

Comment: Yes but before flashing new rom, just have a hard reset. It will make your flashing more efficient.

Comment: I surely will. One more thing is that how can I check if my bootloader is unlocked or not?

Comment: Any help regarding checking bootloader status?

Comment: If you have any os in your android kindly go to developers option and there will be OEM unlock, check it right. If you dont have any os then it might be unlocked by default.

Comment: I just checked and there is an option “Enable OEM Unlock”. What I understand is that I should check this option then root and install custom recovery and then flash a custom rom right? Also please let me know can I downgrade from current 6.0 to something like lollipop?

Comment: You can download different types of cyanogenmod from google which contain different Android OS versions and can have different custom os by installing them.

Comment: Yeah sure but I have read on xda that some devices have downgrade protection and can’t be downgraded, rendering the device unusable

Comment: Downgrading your android using custom rom doesnt affect your hardware or software in any manner. You need yo just find a bugless rom compatible with your smart phone and thats all

Comment: I see. Also while searching for some roms I came to see that some roms offer flashable-modem.zip as separate file in addition to bootloader.zip. Should I install the complete rom and then install both of these files on top of it?

Comment: Yes install full rom.